# How to write common function for keypress function check for floating number of a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, floating-point, numbers

I want to call a common function for more than 2 textboxes so that keypress can check that only floating point number can take a input.

This is my sample code: this work only for a single textbox (`tbL1Distance`). But  I want it as a common textbox control.

```
private void tbL1Distance_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (ch == 46 && tbL1Distance.Text.IndexOf('.') != -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a new control, inherit the TextBox, and override the `OnKeyPress()` method.

Comment: Will you please help me to give the code sample. or edit my code. please. @VisualVincent

Comment: Yes, give me a few minutes...

Comment: Yay, it's gone one hour. Sorry for taking so long, I was busy writing another answer. I am writing this one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create your own control, inheriting the `TextBox`, where you override the `OnKeyPress` method.

```
public class CustomTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (ch == 46 && this.Text.IndexOf('.') != -1) //Replaced 'tbL1Distance' with 'this' to refer to the current TextBox.
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

When done, go to the `Build` menu and press `Build <your project name here>`, and your control can now be found on the top of your Tool Box. Now just replace every normal `TextBox` with your own.

[image: Building a project]

If you don't want the `KeyPress` event to be fired at all if your validation fails, you can just add `return;` in both `if`-statements.

Comment: @Rakib : If this works please mark it as the accepted answer by pressing the green check mark on the left of the post. This will give the answerer +15 reputation points, and the asker of the question +2 reputation points. :)